# Change image onTap

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to change the image every time onTap.
But somehow the image is only getting changed only once.
Please review this piece of code and mention where am I going wrong

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoState createState() => _DemoState();
}

String imagePath = "images/img4.jpg";

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  imagePath = "images/tmhm.jpg";
                });
              },
              child: CircleAvatar(
                maxRadius: 20.0,
                child: Image.asset(imagePath),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your `imagePath` in your State class(`_DemoState`)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoState createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  String imagePath = "images/img4.jpg";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                if(imagePath == "images/img4.jpg"){
                  imagePath = "images/tmhm.jpg";
                }else{
                  imagePath = "images/img4.jpg";
                }
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: CircleAvatar(
                maxRadius: 20.0,
                child: Image.asset(imagePath),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Image is getting changed only once.

Comment: Thank You sir!!!
This code worked completely fine
And I was missing the if else part.

Comment: Please help me solve this problem...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62922353/unable-to-display-a-dialog-box-when-the-all-the-ontap-feature-has-been-exhausted
@JideGuru